# Everything become so small specially text in build a ionic app on High resolution screen like iPhone 6Plus

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am developing an app using ionic framework. My app contain mainly List and input forms.

Everything is so small when testing on iPhone 6Plus. I guess it is because iPhone 6Plus has high resolution. Text is hard to read.

is there a way to scale up everything according to resolution device? And how much should I scale up, any best practice?

In fact, I don't sass, therefore I don't how to using its variable and scale text up using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't post your CSS code, I don't know if this will work for you.

If you're using pt or px for your text you should switch to em or %. 
in general, **1em = 12pt = 16px = 100%**.